I am trying to insert randomly generated numbers into an empty table using a cursor
I am trying to insert randomly generated numbers into an empty table using a cursor but I want it to go through all possible combinations with out having duplicates of the same number and I want to add conditions to what needs to be inserted. I want it to run through the code multiple times, I don't want to have to execute it to the whole time to get like 1 million rows.
So I want to know how would I add conditions to the insert?
and Would I need to create a proc for it to run multiple times?
DECLARE @iNumber1 INT
        ,@iNumber2 INT
        ,@iNumber3 INT
        ,@iNumber4 INT
        ,@iNumber5 INT
        ,@iNumber6 INT
        ,@iNumber7 INT
        ,@iNumber8 INT
        ,@iNumber9 INT
        ,@iNumber10 INT
 
DECLARE GenRandNum CURSOR FOR 
SELECT ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS binary(6)) %50) + 1 AS Number1
,ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS binary(6)) %50) + 1 AS Number2
,ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS binary(6)) %50) + 1 AS Number3
,ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS binary(6)) %50) + 1 AS Number4
,ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS binary(6)) %50) + 1 AS Number5
,ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS binary(6)) %50) + 1 AS Number6
,ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS binary(6)) %50) + 1 AS Number7
,ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS binary(6)) %50) + 1 AS Number8
,ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS binary(6)) %50) + 1 AS Number9
,ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS binary(6)) %50) + 1 AS Number10

 
OPEN GenRandNum 
FETCH NEXT FROM GenRandNum INTO @iNumber1, @iNumber2, @iNumber3, @iNumber4, @iNumber5, @iNumber6, @iNumber7, @iNumber8, @iNumber9, @iNumber10 
 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO GenNumbers (Number1, Number2, Number3, Number4, Number5, Number6, Number7, Number8, Number9, Number10) 
    VALUES (@iNumber1, @iNumber2, @iNumber3, @iNumber4, @iNumber5, @iNumber6, @iNumber7, @iNumber8, @iNumber9, @iNumber10 ) 
 
    FETCH NEXT FROM GenRandNum INTO @iNumber1, @iNumber2, @iNumber3, @iNumber4, @iNumber5, @iNumber6, @iNumber7, @iNumber8, @iNumber9, @iNumber10
END 
 
CLOSE GenRandNum 
DEALLOCATE GenRandNum

the help would be greatly appreciated

And do you have a problem with this task? Do you want to ask a question?

Why do you want to use a CURSOR? Generally that is the last thing you should be using.

So, to clarify, you want to generate a number, between 1 and 50, 10 times, and then get every permutation of those numbers? That's 50^10 (97,656,250,000,000,000) rows! And then you want an arbitrary 1,000,000 of those rows?

I thought a cursor would be the right way to proceed since I wanted it to insert the row of random numbers then proceed to the next row and insert the new row of random numbers

In truth, if you're inserting 10 randomly generated numbers into 10 columns, the chances of getting a collision where 2 rows have the same 10 number is tiny... I'd just put a unique constraint on the table, and if you get a collision, run the statement again, the chances of that happening twice is infinitesimal.

yes and If I need to generate more numbers I could just increase the amount of times it needs to run.

Im not worried if the same number is in two different rows, i just dont want the same number to show in the same row

This is stuff that should be explained in your question... [Edit] it to properly explain the problem; provide expending results (and non-expected results).

You don't need a cursor for this If you use a Numbers table you can replicate as many rows as you want. NEWID() is a bad choice for random numbers though, as only a few bytes of it are actually random. Unless you don't really care about randomness, just different-enough values

@PanagiotisKanavos CHECKSUM(NEWID()) is random enough, more random than RAND() apparently.

Random numbers may result in all of the values in one row being the same and that row could repeat. Perhaps you need a better description, e.g. each row should be filled with 10 distinct values pulled from a pool of 50 values. That still allows repeated rows. You may want to visit Random.org for more information and truly random numbers.

There is no need for a cursor. Just use GENERATE_SERIES
INSERT INTO GenNumbers
    (Number1, Number2, Number3, Number4, Number5, Number6, Number7, Number8, Number9, Number10)
SELECT
  CHECKSUM(NEWID()),
  CHECKSUM(NEWID()),
  CHECKSUM(NEWID()),
  CHECKSUM(NEWID()),
  CHECKSUM(NEWID()),
  CHECKSUM(NEWID()),
  CHECKSUM(NEWID()),
  CHECKSUM(NEWID()),
  CHECKSUM(NEWID()),
  CHECKSUM(NEWID())
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 1000000);


If I add a where clause to filter out the generated numbers will it generate new numbers to create 1 million total generated numbers or will it only filter the 1st million numbers generated?

You'd need to subquery it to do that. It will filter down the 1m to below that. Or you can generate more than 1m, then filter it down and take the TOP (1000000). What sort of filtering do you need?

I want to filter out the rows that have repeated numbers in a single row.  @Charlieface

So what's stopping you doing that. Like I said, just use a subquery and do a bunch of camparisons for all cases.
